# Setting the time on a button in a different Activity in Android

Tags: android

In my application I have two activities.  In the first activity I have a button, and in the second activity I have another button.  My problem is, when the user presses the first button I want to set the time display on the second button in the second activity.  Can any one help me with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value of one button to the second activity:

```
String text = button.getText();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("time", text);
```

---

in second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
  String time = intent.getExtras().getString("time");
}
```